# Java reference instance variable instead of entire map

Tags: java, performance

Someone made the suggestion in my code to save the value of 
HEADER_PROPERTY instead of the entire properties map. First of all I'm
confused on what good that does and secondly I'm confused on how to do it.
this.properties references a property a user inputs on the front end. Valuemap
is a way to access properties of a resource. GetHeaderMessage simply outputs the value of

```
private static final String HEADER_PROPERTY = "header-msg";  
private ValueMap properties = null;
private static final String getHeader = this.properties.get(HEADER_PROPERTY, "");

public void setProperties(ValueMap properties){
this.properties = properties;
}

public String getHeaderMessage(){               
String headerMessage = this.properties.get(HEADER_PROPERTY);
return headerMessage;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question nor your posted code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm able to achieve what I need to. Which basically grabs a property 
a user inputs and displays it. I just don't understand why a suggestion
was made to save the value of HEADER_PROPERTY instead of the entire properties map.
I'm wondering if anyone a) understands that b) can improve upon my code in anyway.

Comment: Because you simply do not need anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a potential optimization since you're reading from that Value Map every single time `getHeaderMessage()` is called to get what we're guessing is a static value that never changes after initialization?  If the implementation of that `ValueMap` reads from hard disk every time it is accessed, and `getHeaderMessage()` is called on every page load, that could be pretty wasteful.  It could be a change as simple as:

```
private static final String HEADER_PROPERTY = "header-msg";  
private ValueMap properties = null;
private String headerMessage = null;
// What is going on with this line?  that doesn't compile.
//private static final String getHeader = this.properties.get(HEADER_PROPERTY, "");

public void setProperties(ValueMap properties){
this.properties = properties;
headerMessage = this.properties.get(HEADER_PROPERTY);
}

public String getHeaderMessage(){
return headerMessage;
}
```

Of course if the contents of that map do actually change after initialization, then it doesn't help.